# Некорректно работает подсчет среднего значения в матрице

Tags: c++

В общем есть такая задача: Вычислить средние арифметические значения неотрицательных элементов каждой строки матрицы [N;M].
Я написал код и сначала подумал что он считает все правильно, но как оказалось, это не так. Среднее значение выходить не правильным. Я пробовал как и с рандомными значениями так и со значениями, которые пользователь вводить с помощью клавиатуры. Скорее всего я что-то проморгал и не могу найти. Заранее спасибо.

Вот код:

```
srand(time(0));
    const int row = 3;
    const int col = 4;
    int m[row][col];
    int k = 0;
    float s = 0;
    float av;

    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
        {

            cin >> m[i][j]; //= rand() % 10 - 1;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
        {
            if ( m[i][j] >= 0 )
            {
                s += m[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
        av = s / k;
        cout << endl;
        cout << av << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Не выносите объявления переменных в начало функции, уже не 1970 год. Проблема в том, что `s` и `k` не обнуляются.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
{
    s = 0.0;
    av = 0.0;
    k = 0;
    for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
    {
        if ( m[i][j] >= 0 )
        {
            s += m[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (k > 0)
        av = s / k;
    cout << endl;
    cout << av << " ";
}
```